# find, xargs and mv: renaming files with double-quotes, expansion and bash precedence issue

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, xargs

Ok, I'm simply trying to strip out double-quotes in my filenames.  Here's the command I came up with (bash).

```
$ find . -iname "*\"*" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} {} | tr -d \"
```

The problem is the `'mv {} {} | tr -d \"'` part.  I think it's a precedence problem: bash seems to be interpreting as `(mv {} {}) | tr -d \")`, and what I'm left with are both filenames stripped of double-quotes.  That's not what I want, obviously, because then it fails to rename the file.  Instead, I want the first filename to have the quotes, and the second not to, more like this: `mv {} ({} | tr -d \")`.

How do I accomplish this?  I've tried brackets and curly braces, but I'm not really sure what I'm doing when it comes to explicitly setting command execution precedence.

Comment: Does your system have the `rename` command that uses regular expressions to rename by patterns?

Comment: @Barmar no, but it looks like I could grab a copy using homebrew - rename version 1.6 from http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename.  Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have the `rename` command installed, use:

```
find . -name '*"*' -exec rename 's/"//g' {} +
```

The `rename` command takes a `Perl` expression to produce the new name. `s/"//g` performs a global substitution of the name, replacing all the quotes with an empty string.

To do it with `mv` you need to pipe to a shell command, so you can execute subcommands:

```
find . -name '*"*' -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "$(printf %s "$0" | tr -d "\"")"' {} \;
```

What you wrote pipes the output of `xargs` to `tr`, it doesn't use `tr` to form the argument to `mv`.

Comment: That worked.  Can you expand your answer to explain why, and if it's possible to do this without rename?

Comment: You might want to replace `echo "$0"` by `printf "%s" "$0"` to avoid issues with file names starting with a dash or containing an escaped character.

Answer (score 3):

```
xargs -0 -I {} mv {} {} | tr -d \"
```

doesn't make sense: `mv` doesn't produce output. Thus you cannot build pipelines with `mv`.

```
find . -name '*"*' -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1//\"/}"' bash {} \;
```

or with less overhead

```
find . -name '*"*' -exec bash -c 'for file in "$@"; do mv "$file" "${file//\"/}"; done' bash {} +
```

Comment: Aha, cool.  That helps me understand why it didn't work, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might do...

```
mkdir ../_cp
pax -Xwrl -s'/"//gp' . "${PWD%/*}/_cp"
```

That just creates a bunch of hardlinks to all files in the hierarchy rooted at `.` in `../_cp`. You can then verify everything is well with both directories before removing one of them - they are pretty much the same directories after all, except in one directory there are no filenames which contain a `"`.